# NoMethodError in StaticPages#home

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, database, production-environment

I get the following error.  Can someone help me figure this out for me, please?

```
Showing /home/bdme551/bdme21/app/views/layouts/application.html.erb where line #4 raised:

undefined method `full_title' for #<#<Class:0x000000048c7d60>:0x000000048be210>
```

Please let me know, if you additional info.

From application.html.erb

```
<title><%= full_title(yield(:title)) %></title>
```

Comment: Where is `full_title` defined? Also, where is the view code you are providing a value for the content `title`?

Comment: in app/views/layouts/application.html.erb

Comment: Please add that code. It will be difficult to assist you with out seeing all relevant code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the information you provided. You have not defined the method `full_title` you should define the method in `helpers/application_helper.rb` so the method will be accessible throughout your pages.

**application_helper.rb**

```
  def full_title(title)
    default_title = "My Website 2.0"
    if title.empty?
      default_title
    else
      "#{title}"
    end
  end
```

**application.html.erb**

```
<title><%= full_title(yield(:title)) %></title>
```

**To change the title page call** `provide`

```
<% provide(:title, "Inbox") %>
```

hope that helps!